# window.onbeforeunload listener not triggering on tab close in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, local-storage

**The Problem**

I have a function that should run on window.onbeforeunload. In Chrome, this works correctly and runs whenever a tab or window is closed or refreshed. In Firefox, however, it only runs on refresh, not close.

**The Code**

Here is an example:

```
var onStorageUpdate = function(){
    var lastUnloaded = localStorage.getItem("LastUnloaded");
    if(lastUnloaded === null){
        $("div").text("Never stored");
    }
    else{
        $("div").text(lastUnloaded);
    }
};

onStorageUpdate();

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(){
    var now = Date.now();
    localStorage.setItem("LastUnloaded", now);
});

window.addEventListener("storage", function(){
    onStorageUpdate();
});
```

Here is the order of events that *should* work in the above code:

1. On initial page load, attempt to get `LastUnloaded` from localStorage. If nothing is retrieved, show "Never Stored", otherwise show the value that was stored (should be a long integer timestamp)
2. Upon unloading a tab, updated `LastUnloaded` with the current timestamp. *This is the part that doesn't seem to work in Firefox when closing a window.*
3. Upon change in localStorage, update the DOM to show the timestamp

**Demo**

Here is a codepen of the example: http://codepen.io/jakelauer/full/NqRyqQ/

In order to test it, open the link in two different windows or tabs. You should notice that when you refresh either tab, both tabs update to show the same timestamp. In Chrome, you will notice that if you close one tab, the other tab will update its timestamp. In Firefox, you will notice that the timestamp **does not get updated**.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure why someone put in a "close" request? This question is clearly about programming.

Comment: According to [Mozilla's Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) the intent of the `beforeunload` event is to provide a way to prompt users and allow them to cancel the page unload. Their docs also indicate great variation in browser implementation of the standard for that event. So for starters, you should probably be using the `unload` event for this. I have also heard anecdotally that one shouldn't rely on `unload` events running because of inconsistent behavior across browsers.

Comment: @maurice And you can use it to save page state, you do not need to prompt the user with it.

Comment: @epascarello true, but the question is whether the saving of page state is meant to take place before or after the possible cancellation of the `unload`. If you were saving a key like `lastAttemptedUnload`, it might belong in a `beforeunload` handler. Being called `LastUnloaded`, I assumed the intent was to capture actual events where the page had been unloaded.

Comment: @Jake if you refresh the page that you did not close did the storage key get updated in Firefox? If so, does manually changeling the storage key in another tab cause the onstorage to update? Maybe Firefox does not support the event across tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using onunload, which worked fine everywhere.